# Load methods/properties/module from Scikit-Learn in PyCharm

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 3.4.1 (professional version). And I am exploring Scikit-Learn, NumPy etc. But unfortunately I can't get methods/properties/module in PyCharm when I write code with any installed package instead of Python core. Though when I import any module at the beginning of any .py file, it shows the corresponding methods/modules after pressing dot(.), but in code, PyCharm does not show the list after pressing dot(.).

How I can get all things after pressing dot(.)?

Thanks!